# WP Media Library To Upload Images From Theme Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I have this project from my college that I almost done. I have been messing around with wp_enque_media(), which works fine on WP admin portal. But when I try the same code for frontend admin, it opens up the library UI but doesn't allow to upload images.

Front end admin console credentials are saved in a new custom table (i.e. its not wp user login).

I have added below code as I understand from console error:

`wp_localize_script('ajax-image-upload','ajax_image_object',array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))));`

But it doesn't make any difference.

```
function shpg_admin_dashboard_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('shpg_js_front_admin_property', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/js/admin-property.js', '', '',  true);
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_localize_script('ajax-image-upload','ajax_image_object',array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))));
} 

function shpg_check_admin_dashboard_page($arg) { // To Check Frontend Admin
    if($arg == 'admin-dashboard'){
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shpg_admin_dashboard_scripts');
    }
}
```

Looking for help to be able to upload images from front end admin dashboard.

Currently it gives error on Media librar UI
Error: An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

Also when looked at console, it gives error:

> Root**/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Looking forward if any gentleman can help.